# Windows 8.1 Pro MinGW Gfortran Command Prompt 'not recognized command' error

Tags: windows, fortran, mingw, windows-8.1, gfortran

> C:\Users\redacted\Documents\redacted>gfortran hibrac.f -o hibrac.exe
>
> 'gfortran' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesWindows seems similar to my problem: gfortran.exe is in C:\Windows\MinGW\bin -- except the solution appears not to apply to Windows 8.1 Pro:

> Right click on My Computer, Properties, Advanced Tab, Environment Variables.

Instead I tried: Right click on 'This PC' within File Explorer, Properties, Advanced system settings, Advanced Tab -- and I cannot find an equivalent-looking section that allows me to proceed with the advised solution.

As background information:

I had installed MinGW Installation Manager which installed mingw32-gcc-fortran (together with mingw32-base, -gcc-g++, and -gcc-objc) in the recommended C:\Windows\MinGW folder, without any apparent error message.

Isn't it acceptable -- standard practice -- to have one's code in a folder separate from this MinGW folder? i.e. a subdirectory of my Users\account rather than a subdirectory of MinGW. This isn't the problem, is it? What do I need to do to get it to recognize the gfortran.exe, or call it correctly?

Please tell me what to do to get it working. If it's relevant, I have a Japanese computer with an English language pack installed (it seems to have some gaps, such as some text in the Settings charm or startup/shutdown text being in Japanese).

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like you have neglected to add C:\MinGW\bin to the effective PATH for the command window, in which you are attempting to run the gfortran command.

Your question isn't entirely specific on this point, (i.e. you could improve the question), but you hint that you were unable to add the appropriate PATH entry to the global environment variables, because you couldn't find the appropriate control panel applet? I know that this is often recommended as part of a MinGW setup, but the installer will not do it for you, because I, as the maintainer of mingw-get, don't consider that to be best practice; much better, IMO, to add it for each specific command window in which you need it to take effect, by running (once, at the start of each command prompt session) the command:

```
path %PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin
```

If you prefer, you may create a batch file to do this for you, along with any other initializations you wish to perform, (or better still, use MSYS as the working shell environment, in which case the PATH initialization is taken care of by the shell's own initialization scripts).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but before I try that command in the Command Prompt, it seems wise to to clarify that there's much I don't understand:
1a. Must I execute this path command every time I open the Command Prompt?
1b. Or must I execute it once per directory that I'm working in?
2. Yes, I couldn't find where to go in the Control Panel. You say much that is beyond my computer knowledge: global environment variables, initializations, MSYS, shell environment. I don't know these.

I read http://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/ but didn't see the answers to these questions.

Comment: @Scott, you need to do it just once for each command prompt session; usually it's the first thing you do, after starting each command prompt window. Putting it in the global environment, (i.e. by setting it in the "environment variables" control panel applet), saves you having to do it each time, but passes it to _every_ process you run thereafter; for the vast majority, it's just noise and unnecessary clutter. OTOH, MSYS is an alternative to the standard command prompt; it's more capable, and can perform such per session initializations automatically.

Comment: @Scott, Windows command prompt also used to support per session initialization, using `CONFIG.SYS` or `AUTOEXEC.BAT` scripts. I no longer use Windows, and I don't know if that capability is still supported.